# react-admin error: 'Cannot read properties of undifined (reading 'id')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, httprequest, react-admin

In react-admin library, when I try to post an object via http-request with the schema in the backend (id, firstname, lastname, email) with the id is autogenerated, It shows the error message : 'Cannot read properties of undifined (reading 'id')"

this is the code of Create component:

```
const TeacherCreate = (props) => {
return (
<Create title="Teachers form" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm validate={validateUserCreation}>
        <TextInput source="firstname" />
        <TextInput source="lastname"/>
        <TextInput source="email" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
)
}

export default TeacherCreate
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What does the `validateUserCreation` function look like?

Comment: It works just fine now... It needs that the backend returns an object (the same which added).